# Rerouting Bluetooth traffic

Tags: java, windows, bluetooth

I have 3rd party application on one computer (Comp A) that communicates with a 3rd party device via a bluetooth dongle. 
I would like to connect the 3rd party device to a different computer (comp B) by a real dongle attached to comp B, and reroute or clone the traffic or stream from the application on comp A, via TCP/IP, to bluetooth dongle in computer B. Then re-transmit the stream using a this dongle.
In other words, I'm interested in establishing a virtual link between comp A and the bluetooth dongle in Comp B, such that any application on comp A will be invisible to the change.
Note that I'm not interested in decoding the packet contents, but rather have a 1-1 copy or transfer the packets.

What would be the best option to do so?
I thought of two options:
1) create a virtual bluetooth dongle, configure the 3rd party to use this dongle,
and then transmit the bit-stream that is sent by this dongle to the different computer.
2) Somehow clone or sniff the packets that are sent to the virtual driver and resend them by means of TCP/IP protocol to another computer.

First, What would you recommended me to do? What building blocks are available (e.g, the virtual bluetooth windows driver)? I would be very helpful if you can send me some links/tips that will help in performing this task.

Second, what programming language best suits for the task? I thought the Java would fit best since I later contemplate with replacing comp B by an android device.

Finally, how long do you think it would take me, a beginner-intermediate programmer, to create this application?

Thanks ahead!